# Angular Material some css variables are undefined with standalone component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, css-variables

I'm using Angular 15 and `@angular/material`.  I've created a standalone component that uses the `mat-dialog-title`, `mat-dialog-content`, and `mat-dialog-actions`.  This component, as you can probably tell, is being used with the `MatDialog`.  Unfortunately, when I render the component in the dialog, some of the css variables coming from material are undefined for some reason, while others are not.

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why some of the variables would be defined, but not others.  This is causing the styling to look pretty weird.  Is there a dependent module I need to import besides `MatDialogModule` in the standalone component?

Since the component is standalone, I figured this didn't matter, but the component is located in a separate library project (exported from there).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with Angular Material version 16.1.6. I searched for hours to find the issue in the SCSS files of @angular/material, but i couldn't find it.

The last try was to update to the latest Angular Material version (in my case 16.2.0) and the CSS variables suddenly appeared.

I had a look at the changes and it seems they removed some legacy stuff. I cannot really say what the issue was :/

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar error.

I try to define custom css props in the scss file of a standalone component like this:

```
:root {
        --card-padding: 32px;
        --card-padding-half: 16px;
        --card-padding-xs: 16px;
}
```

For some reason, I can't even access these custom props IN THE SAME Angular component scss!

=> It seems like angular does something fancy with the ':root' pseudo-element when running in a standalone component.

Comment: I would definitely avoid providing an answer to a question on StackOverflow that isn't actually an answer to the question.